# How do I handle has_many in wordpress? (discography->songs->5 urls per song)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm coding a wordpress for a band and on their discography page they want the following:

1. Album cover image
2. Title
3. Release date
4. List of 10 or so songs that they can click to play...

Then next to EACH song needs to be 5 different icons (video, lyrics, play, amazon link, itunes link).

At first I was going to use a custom post type, but considering that's only 1 dimension of data i dont know what to do, as they have to add like 10 songs for each album, and then the 5 urls associated with each song.

How might i do this with custom post types? or is there a plugin that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like that, look into Custom Fields (http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

This plugin would help
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

Though it is possible (but a lot to explain) to code them yourself. The aforementioned plugin will do a lot of that for you.

Comment: thanks for that, i remember that plugin in the past and i was looking for it. my question is, what specific 'thing' should i be looking for or doing with this plugin to add that 'extra layer' of data for each entry. for each 'album' they need to enter 10 songs, and for each song, 5 links. I can get the grip of this pretty fast if you could perhaps point me in the right direction as far as what type of basic setup I'd need to do.

Comment: It'd be cleaner with a custom setup, but with the plugin, create a key for each song (song1, song2, song3, etc), and (this gets a bit dirty), a key for each link (song1_video, song1_lyrics, song1_play, etc).  
You'll be able to call them using the key like so: get_post_meta($post->ID, 'song1', true);

Comment: would they be able to add new albums + songs easily on their own? or do they need to edit all kinds of things in the plugin if they were to do that. if its possible from just the client end POV, awesome! much appreciated

Comment: Make it a custom post type just for albums and once you configure the Custom Field Plugin for that Post Type, the custom fields will be there for every new post. I've been meaning to write a tutorial on how to add custom fields and meta boxes to Wordpress so a plugin isn't required but just haven't found time yet.

Comment: No problem! If you run into problems let me know.